# NSFetchedResultsController issue on iOS4

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I am developing an application which uses CoreData. The view contains a UITableView (containing around 50 elements) which uses a NSFetchedResultsController. There is also a "Pull to refresh" which permits to refresh the stored data after a WS call (in another thread with a new managed object context).

Everything is working fine on iOS5: the database and the tableview are refreshed when I perform a "Pull to refresh". However there is a problem with iOS4. The first "performFetch" works when the application is launched (the tableview contains all database records) but I've got the following error when I perform a "Pull to refresh":

```
2012-02-29 11:56:09.119 Nanopost[1996:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception      'NSObjectInaccessibleException', reason: 'CoreData could not fulfill a fault for '0x5c3c760 <x-coredata://E176B0A1-275B-4332-9231-49FD88238C2B/Ads/p231>''
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x02bfe919 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02e595de objc_exception_throw + 47
2   CoreData                            0x028b833f _PFFaultHandlerLookupRow + 1407
3   CoreData                            0x028b5ee3 _PF_FulfillDeferredFault + 499
4   CoreData                            0x028b9f3f _sharedIMPL_pvfk_core + 95
5   CoreData                            0x0292a010 _PF_Handler_Public_GetProperty + 160
6   Foundation                          0x02442c4f -[NSSortDescriptor compareObject:toObject:] + 128
7   CoreData                            0x0297db5e +[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _insertIndexForObject:inArray:lowIdx:highIdx:sortDescriptors:] + 286
8   CoreData                            0x0297e1b2 -[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _postprocessInsertedObjects:] + 402
9   CoreData                            0x029841bc -[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _managedObjectContextDidChange:] + 1804
10  Foundation                          0x02380c1d _nsnote_callback + 145
11  CoreFoundation                      0x02bd6cf9 __CFXNotificationPost_old + 745
12  CoreFoundation                      0x02b5611a _CFXNotificationPostNotification + 186
13  Foundation                          0x023767c2 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 134
14  CoreData                            0x028c0519 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalNotificationHandling) _postObjectsDidChangeNotificationWithUserInfo:] + 89
15  CoreData                            0x028f802b -[NSManagedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:] + 1579
16  Foundation                          0x02395e9a __NSThreadPerformPerform + 251
17  CoreFoundation                      0x02bdfd7f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
18  CoreFoundation                      0x02b3e2cb __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 571
19  CoreFoundation                      0x02b3d7c6 __CFRunLoopRun + 470
20  CoreFoundation                      0x02b3d280 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
21  CoreFoundation                      0x02b3d1a1 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
22  GraphicsServices                    0x031e62c8 GSEventRunModal + 217
23  GraphicsServices                    0x031e638d GSEventRun + 115
24  UIKit                               0x0063cb58 UIApplicationMain + 1160
25  Nanopost                            0x0000230a main + 170
26  Nanopost                            0x00002255 start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of '_NSCoreDataException'
```

When I initialize the "NSFetchRequest", I set the "FetchBatchSize" to 20 (randomly):

```
[l_FetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];
```

But if I set the "FetchBatchSize" to 25:

```
[l_FetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:25];
```

... No more crashes on iOS4 and I don't know why and I want to understand this issue :) I don't think that this line is the real problem. Maybe it indicates another problem somewhere?

Thank you very much in advance for your answers!

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are using a different context? I don't switch mine, and I have a pretty similar sounding app.

One thing you might compare to is this very handy CoreDataTableViewController:

http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/node/289

I use it and haven't had any issues (though I am not running in iOS 4). You might compare how you hooked up the fetchedResultsController.

One other point - do you have the catch-all breakpoint to push the debugger as soon as an exception is raised? If not, add it (breakpoints, + to add, "Add Exception Breakpoint" and keep defaults). That will put you into the debugger right on the line that raises the exception, which should be useful.

Good luck,

Damien

Comment: Hi Damien and thank you for your answer!

I use a different context because it seems to be a "best practice" according to the Apple's documentation (Another thread = Another managed object context).

I tried to add an "Exception breakpoint". Unfortunately the exception is thrown in main.m file so it's not easy to have a clue about this issue.

Thomas

Comment: Exception in main.m means it wasn't handled and unwound the entire stack. Your exception breakpoint will raise as soon as it is thrown - try again until it works, it's key to see exactly where the program is when it breaks.